# Does Latest version of iTextPdf(i.e. 5.5.5) support Hindi Language?

Tags: itext, itextpdf

I had seen on [www.itextpdf.com](http://www.itextpdf.com/) that iText has recently released version 5.5.5.

Does it fully support Hindi language? Because I am facing problem in Hindi ligature.

Before buying iTextPdf this I want to know whether this support Hindi language or not.

Comment: No, but we are working on it. For an ETA, please contact iText Software.

Comment: by when it will be released as paid module?

Comment: I don't know. That's why I advised you to contact iText Software.